# Access web service from external network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip-address, web-services

I'm trying to deploy a web service (wsdl) on a machine running Ubuntu 12.04 and access it service via external network, i.e. the internet.

At first, I tested with apache2 by starting it and accessing a simple website via `http://<ip-adress>/`. It worked fine

Secondly, I stopped apache2 and started my service running on port 80. My service could be access locally via `http://localhost/` but was inaccessible using `http://<ip-address>`

I wonder if I missed something or apaches contained external features allowing service to be access externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of web servers / frameworks just bind to 127.0.0.1 (lo) interface.

What software are you using for running the web service ?

Look if you can specify address anywhere. Set to 0.0.0.0.

With Apache it worked because the connection from it to you web service was through localhost.